# How to customize dispatch rules in Perl's Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst

How do you customize dispatch rules Catalyst are using when matching an url?

For example, I'd like `GET /home/a` to call into `sub a_GET : Local` and `POST /home/a` to call `sub a_POST : Local`.

I know that I can always write a common action that will call one of those functions based on the name but I'd like to hear about more generic options.

Answer (score 5):

[Catalyst::Controller::REST](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aController%3a%3aREST)

Comment: Thanks. Project by itself is useless to me but the source code helped me understand Catalyst magic better.